# Autocommit / Softcommit doesn't work when I'm using CURL

Tags: solr

I got a problem using the autocommit and softcommit features.

I use this syntax with curl to update my data :

```
curl $url/solr/update/csv -F "stream.file=$folder/$file" -F  "commit=false" -F "header=false" -F "fieldnames=`cat $header`"
```

I've set in my solrconfig.xml the autocommit :

```
<autoCommit> 
  <maxTime>10000</maxTime> 
  <openSearcher>false</openSearcher> 
</autoCommit>
```

I've indexed a collection of documents and at the end of indexing (it takes some minutes to index) NO documents are visible in my solr admin... when I reload or when I do an explicit commit, then all my documents are visible.

I know that if I change "commit=false" in "commit=true" all my documents will be indexed. But I know that is not a good behaviour to do a commit after each update.

Do I miss something with the setting of the AutoCommit and SoftCommit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Sample Solrconfix.xml](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/example/solr/collection1/conf/solrconfig.xml) file in the `<autoCommit>` section.

> Perform a hard commit automatically under certain conditions.
>            Instead of enabling autoCommit, consider using "commitWithin"
>            when adding documents.

From the the [CommitWithin Wiki Page](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommitWithin).

> CommitWithin is a commit strategy introduced in Solr 1.4, which lets the client ask Solr to make sure this `<add>` gets committed within a certain time. This leaves the control of when to do the commit to Solr itself, optimizing number of commits to a minimum while still fulfilling the update latency requirements. If I say `<add commitWithin=10000>` (in an XMLUpdateRequestHandler update), that tells Solr to make sure the document gets committed within 10000ms, i.e. 10s. I can then continue to add other documents within those 10 seconds (possibly with other commitWithin values), and Solr will automatically do a `<commit>` when the oldest  in the buffer is due.

I have been using commitWithin on almost all of my index updates for the last year or more and have seen much better results than the `<autoCommit>` setting in the solrconfig.xml. You can specify this parameter when making your curl request by changing your `"commit=false"` to `"comitWithin=10000"` as follows:

```
 curl $url/solr/update/csv -F "stream.file=$folder/$file" -F  "commitWithin=10000" -F "header=false" -F "fieldnames=`cat $header`"
```

Comment: Thank you to reply ! I'll try the commitWithin feature. But one more question, can I write something like this to try autocommit and soft commit : curl $url/solr/update/csv -F "stream.file=$folder/$file" -F  "autoCommit=10000" -F "header=false" -F "fieldnames=`cat $header`". Is it a right syntax ? I need to compare the indexing performance of these different commit strategy.

Comment: CommitWithin is essentially the autoCommit exposed via a url parameter as it exposes the same behavior only at a per document level and not across the entire index. SoftCommit is not exposed AFAIK. Here is a listing of the available commit parameters - http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateXmlMessages#A.22commit.22_and_.22optimize.22

Comment: Great ! there is everything that I need. Thank a lot.